# Get closest div inside clicked <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I'm trying to get the closest DIV inside a li item, to apply a new class:

```
  <ul id="menu">
    <li class="here">
      <img src="image">
      <div class="border selected"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="here">
      <img src="image">
      <div class="border"></div>
    </li>
                            .....
```

I wanted to be able to click inside the li tag and apply the class 'selected' to the div that already has class border.

I was trying to use .closest and .find but I couldn't get the good result.
Is there any recommendation? Thanks!

EDIT: https://jsfiddle.net/a8pm1aj7/

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself

Comment: you dont need closest just use find

Comment: @guradio - he did, but he couldn't get the good result - apparently, maybe he got line 37 wrong

Comment: *"I was trying to use .closest and .find but I couldn't get the good result"* - Show us what you tried exactly.

Comment: please include a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so people could help. We're not miracle workers here.

Comment: @JaromandaX i thought when said `use .closest and .find` he used it together when he only needs `.find()`

Comment: Sorry for being vague. $('#menu li').on('click',function(e){      $(this).closest('div').find('.border').addClass('selected');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look at this [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/richbuff/1ztsm6m6/).

The relevant code is:

```
$("#menu li").on("click", function(){
  $("#menu li div.border").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).find("div.border").addClass("selected");
});
```

This code removes the `.selected` class from all previously selected elements.

If I understand your question correctly, this should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

`.children()` seems to work fine.... You may have more of an issue with CSS hierarchy. Make certain the `selected` class is defined *after* the `border` class in the CSS.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $( '.here' ).on('click', function() {
      var theDiv = $(this).children('.border');
      $('.border').not(theDiv).removeClass('selected');
     $( theDiv ).toggleClass('selected');
  });
  
  
  });
```

```css
li { display: block; margin: 10px; width: 80%; }

.border { height: 20px; background: #eee; }
.selected { background: #fee; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <ul id="menu">
        <li class="here">
          Text/image
          <div class="border"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="here">
          Text/image
          <div class="border"></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/a8pm1aj7/1/) and *fixed issues with it*. 
- You had the div positioned absolute and set at 100% width and 100% height. S0 basically, it was the size of the window. Actually *linked* the jQuery library to the fiddle.

Comment: But in the case to toggle between the items? (only 1 selected)

Comment: Updated answer so only 1 div is highlighted at a time.

Comment: Slight tweak to snippet for proper toggling.